# Problem with keyboard language indicator

Tags: keyboard

Good morning to all.
I use two languages in my laptop. English US and Greek languages. In my first installation of Elementary the indicator was at the top right corner without to do something special for this. After a problem I reinstall Elementary and it's not possible anymore to see the indicator. It's difficult to work because I don't know every time what language I'm using. The OS is Elementary 5.1.7 Hera. Any idea? Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The following steps helped me, if I'm not mistaken: removing all languages, adding English (US) and a second language.

Comment: Indeed!! Thanks a lot. Easy fix :-)