# Configuring the wing panel

Tags: wingpanel, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I lost the keyboard layout indicator from the wing panel. I reinstalled the system language settings and keyboard settings, but it didn't help. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with keyboard language indicator](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25915/problem-with-keyboard-language-indicator)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by deleting all languages in keyboard settings, and re-adding them again, as stated in this post:

[Problem with keyboard language indicator](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/25915/problem-with-keyboard-language-indicator)